# Grid Layout and Border Layout

Tags: java, jpanel, grid-layout, border-layout

So i'm tring to create a start button on the left corner with Border Layout, and 3x3 grid Layout consisting of 9  labels. which must look something like this[The image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PD89.png)

However, I am unable to do so. Here is my code BTW

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Something extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        new Something();
    }


public Something(){
    super("Whack-a-mole");

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(panel1);

    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    start.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 30));
    panel1.add(start,BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    add(panel2.AFTER_LAST_LINE);


    for(int x=1;x<10;x++)
    {
        JLabel labl  = new JLabel("lab"+x);
        panel2.add(labl);
    }



    setSize(400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);



}

}
```

Comment: Use more JPanels each using its own layout and nest them.

Comment: For instance the top JPanel could use BorderLayout, and add the JButton to its BorderLayout.LINE_START position, and then add this JPanel to the main JPanel in the BorderLayout.PAGE_START POSITION.  The key is to keep playing with this. I have confidence with this with enough effort, you really can do this without our help.